# Обучение нейронной сети на распознавание лиц

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Где можно найти код для обучения модели по распознаванию лиц? Гуглю гуглю уже час, выдаёт либо Каскады Хаара, либо уже с обученной моделью. А мне нужно именно самому с помощью датасета эту модель сначала обучить...

Answer (score 0):

Можно взять за основу какой-нибудь notebook на [kagge](https://www.kaggle.com/).
Например вот этот: https://www.kaggle.com/stpeteishii/lfw-people-conv2d